# Error : Call to a member function build() on null in cakephp 3

Tags: helper, cakephp-3.0

I need to use session in my MhtmlHelper.

```
namespace App\View\Helper;
use Cake\View\Helper;
use Cake\View\Helper\HtmlHelper;

class MhtmlHelper extends HtmlHelper {
}
```

When I add this line,

```
public $helpers = ['Session'];
```

in my helper, this error appears.

```
Error: Call to a member function build() on null    
File D:\xampp\htdocs\projects\bookmarker\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\View\Helper\HtmlHelper.php  
Line: 323
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include all helpers that the HtmlHelper need to work:

https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/src/View/Helper/HtmlHelper.php#L40

You can append to that list as many helpers as you may need for your task.